# GNU C: What will happen if i overwrite malloc() free() but not realloc()?

Tags: c, malloc, freertos

I am coding for an embedded system using ARM cross toolchain arm-none-ebi-gcc.  Because the code is running freeRTOS which has its own heap memory management so I want to overwrite malloc(), free() and realloc() in the libc and wrap them simply to call the functions in freeRTOS.  Only one problme, the freeRTOS does not have realloc(), that's strange, but my code definitely need it.  So I want to understand, what will happen if I only overwrite malloc() and free() but still keep the realloc() the version as it be in the libc?  Also, I feel providing my own realloc() that just call malloc() with the new size and do the memcopy after the new memory block got allocated looks not safe enough to my mind, because the new size usually larger than the old size in my application, so when I do a memcopy() with a size larger than the actually allocated memory block will could create some pointer access error, it that possible?

Thanks in advance.
-woody

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partially replacing the allocator (replacing some functions but not others) can't work. At worst, you will get serious heap data structure corruption from one implementation interpreting another's data structures as its own. It's possible to harden against this so that things just fail to link or fail to allocate (provide null pointer results) at runtime if this is done, and I did this in musl libc as described in these commits:

- https://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/commit/src/malloc?id=c9f415d7ea2dace5bf77f6518b6afc36bb7a5732
- https://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/commit/src/malloc?id=618b18c78e33acfe54a4434e91aa57b8e171df89
- https://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/commit/src/malloc?id=b4b1e10364c8737a632be61582e05a8d3acf5690

but I doubt many other implementations take the same precautions. And they won't help what you want actually work; they'd just prevent catastrophic results.

If you really need `realloc`, you're going to have to make a working one for the implementation you're adopting. The easiest way to do that is make it just `malloc`, `memcpy`, and `free`, but indeed you need a way to determine the length argument to pass to `memcpy`. If you just pass the new length, it *might* be safe on a microcontroller without MMU, as long as your lengths aren't so large they risk running over into an MMIO range or something. But the right thing to do is read the `malloc` implementation enough to understand where it's stored the allocated size, and write your own code to extract that. At that point you can write a correct/valid `realloc` using `memcpy`.

Comment: Very helpful. Now I can decide that I have to write a new `realloc` after I can know where the freeRTOS's malloc stored the length info for the previously allocated block. Thank you very much!